# i would like to install debian

Tags: debian

i already made a unallocated space on windows disk management with the size about 10 gbs and is it possible to install Debian into that exact hard drive without partitioning anything?

Comment: Debian != Ubuntu. Try [unix.se]

Comment: It sounds like you've already partitioned your disk by allocating a 10GB partition using Windows Disk Management.  Following instructions for installation, you should be able to use that partition to install Ubuntu.  I'm not quite clear on exactly what you're asking here, but 10GB should be enough for a Debian/Ubuntu installation, but most people would suggest you have more space available than that.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu need at least a primary partition to work. Besides that swap is advisable if you use memory consuming programs. And needed if you want to put the computer in hibernation. If you install Ubuntu it will automatically set up the needed partitions for you when you choose "Install Ubuntu alongside windows".

Comment: thanks for answering somehow debian is not booting when i insert the cd into the tray when i boot up